# How can I generate Ean18 code to SVG with separator by zxing.net?

Tags: c#, zxing.net

I want to generate Ean18 to SVG like this:
[image]

As you see, the code has a lead, separator and trailer.

This question is similar like https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net/discussions/452

However, the solution above using some package only works in Windows and currently I need to run in Linux/MAC/Android/IOS for cross platform.

In addition, that way seems cannot generate to SVG format also.

How can I solve this?

Comment: A quick search shows the following: [Generate QR Codes and Other Barcodes with Camera.MAUI in .NET MAUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERZfz_NX_Wc). For other results search for `.net maui barcode`.

Comment: What is your target version?  To work on Windows/Linux/ and Mac use Core 6.0 or newer.   Read following : https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Getting-Started-Developing

Comment: @jdweng I am using Avalonia to develop cross platform program.

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid I am afraid the Camera.MAUI does not support Linux at all. I am not developing my program by MAUI but Avalonia.

Comment: @jdweng My target version is .net7

Comment: Hope your project isn't something that you're putting much effort into because according to [.NET and .NET Core release lifecycle](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core#lifecycle), support for .NET 7 ends May 2024.

Comment: @Tudeschizieuinchid Ah, I prefer using the newest .net . When .net 8 is published, I will upgrade my project to .Net 8 in the future.